# Don't mistake me for my brother, he's fatter than I am

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

> I am one of many, but one thing's for sure,
> If you are hit by me, your death I'll assure.
>
> Don't blame me if you get hurt, I'm just a kid,
> I'll end the war that's happening. Hope, I'll rid.
>
> I like being in airplanes, and I like skydiving too,
> I grew up in the Alamo. Don't believe me? It's true!
>
> Everyone says I'll change the world, for better or worse,
> All I know is one thing. Use me; you won't need a hearse.

Comment: The Alamo is a Spanish Mission in San Antonio Texas. Alamos on the other hand has a different meaning (Cottonwood Trees)

Comment: @DEEM, I'm well aware (After all, I grew up in Texas ;) ). This was just a play on words here.

Comment: ...A riddle I spend half an hour on gets more views and votes than puzzles and riddles I spend hours working on...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This one seems grim, but are you

> The Little Boy atomic bomb?

I am one of many, but one thing's for sure,

> There was more than one atomic bomb developed

If you are hit by me, your death I'll assure.

> Being hit by one is instant death

Don't blame me if you get hurt, I'm just a kid,

> Nickname "Little Boy"

I'll end the war that's happening. Hope, I'll rid.

> Ended WWII on the Eastern Front

I like being in airplanes, and I like skydiving too,

> Was dropped from an airplane

I grew up in the Alamo. Don't believe me? It's true!

> Developed at Los Alamos Laboratories

Everyone says I'll change the world, for better or worse,

> Beginning of the Atomic Age (post-1945) changed the world

All I know is one thing. Use me; you won't need a hearse.

> Won't need a hearse if there's nothing left

As for the title,

> The other bomb used on Nagasaki was called Fat Man

Comment: You got it before I did

Comment: As grim as it is, this is correct.

Comment: The Alamo is a place in San Antonio Texas where the siege and killing of Americans at the hand of Spanish army occurred. Alamos on the other hand means Cottonwood Trees-- I am told.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know what's the process for accepted answers? Is there a time delay in place (sorry, I'm still quite new!)? Thanks!!

Comment: @El-Guest, Hexonimo once told me to wait around 24 hours before accepting. The reasoning behind this is 2 fold. 1) It'll give you more votes and views. 2) It'll allow people to give interesting answers that may fit even better than your intended answer.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know, thanks very much for the clarification! This is a pretty cool community.

Comment: So *this* was your first answer? Nearly 40 upvotes?! Wow... :D

Comment: @MrPie almost a year ago now! Hard to believe...

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> Water

I am one of many, but one thing's for sure,

> Water is one thing of many you need to live, or it is one of the many things like [earth, wind, fire, water, and metal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_element).

If you are hit by me, your death I'll assure.

> If you fall from to high onto water it is not good.

Don't blame me if you get hurt, I'm just a kid,
I'll end the war that's happening. Hope, I'll rid.

> I am not sure.

I like being in airplanes, and I like skydiving too,

> You need water on airplanes and rain is like water skydiving.

I grew up in the Alamo. Don't believe me? It's true!

> Maybe a river?

Everyone says I'll change the world, for better or worse,

> Water is needed but spoiled water is bad.

All I know is one thing. Use me; you won't need a hearse.

> You need water at least every three days.

Regarding the title

> Water and oil? Oil is fatty.

Comment: Good guess, but this isn't the answer I'm looking for. The answer I'm looking for is very different than this one.

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> Lightning

I am one of many, but one thing's for sure,

> there can be more lightnings in a storm

If you are hit by me, your death I'll assure.

> or maybe God gives you a second chance

Don't blame me if you get hurt, I'm just a kid, I'll end the war that's happening. Hope, I'll rid.

> A lightning lives only few seconds , in the past it could give a sign of war or peace

I like being in airplanes, and I like skydiving too,

> it is skydiving , the part with the airplanes it's scary

I grew up in the Alamo. Don't believe me? It's true!

> Can be born in any city with clouds and then move to another place

Everyone says I'll change the world, for better or worse,

> some say that lightning can be used to get energy and some say that it destroys the planet

All I know is one thing. Use me; you won't need a hearse.

> Using it is better than running from it

Regarding the title

> it can be thunder his brother , it makes larger sounds so it could be more 'fat' ?

Comment: Interesting answer, but some of these don't fit really well. +1 from me, though.